# User Login not working in PHP

Tags: php, sql, authentication

My login doesn't seem to be working in the correct manner. if the user inputs the wrong details then it still directs the user to the logged in page. What could be the problem?

```
$username=$_POST['Username'];
$password=$_POST['Password'];

$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `Username`='$username' AND `Password`='$password'", $con);
if(!$qry) {
  mysql_close($con);
  die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
} else {
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
}

if($_POST['username']==$row["Username"]&&$_POST['password']==$row["Password"])
{
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['Firstname']=$_POST['Username'];
  mysql_close($con);
  header("Location:index_logged_in.php");
}
else
{
  mysql_close($con);
  header ("Location:login.php?id=Incorrect username or password. Please Enter Again.");
}

//This is what is in the logged in page

include('connection2.php');
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['Firstname']) {
   header("");
}
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Please don't post the website name in your question, it would be easy to hack your website with this code. Search google for php mysql injection, also, use === instead of ==.due to php hash vulnerability.

Comment: adding to the list of wrongness here: passwords stored as plain text, still using depreciated mysql_*

Comment: You need to stop using `mysql_*` functions and use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead, you need to use prepared statements with bound parameters, you need to hash your passwords with `password_hash()`

Comment: @Dagon great minds think alike...

Comment: `$_POST['username']` != `$_POST['Username']`

Comment: The correct username and password gets the incorrect login response, I think?

Answer (score 1):

Without addressing any controversial issues, I think this is probably why you aren't getting the result you expect. At the beginning of your code, you use `$username=$_POST['Username'];` and `$password=$_POST['Password'];` to get the username and password, and run your query with those variables. Then later, you use this:

```
if($_POST['username']==$row["Username"]&&$_POST['password']==$row["Password"])
```

If the username and password don't match anything in your database, then `$row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);` will return `false`. Because `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` are not set (`$_POST['Username']` and `$_POST['Password']` are set, note the uppercase U and P) then when you compare those values, you are basically comparing `false` and `null`, which when using `==`, are equal.

Answer (score -4):

I'm OK with `mysql_`.

You should not store the user password, there are some serious liability issues there.

I cleaned up your code.

```
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];
$results = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `Username`='$username' AND `Password`='$password'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($results);
if($rows > 0){
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['Firstname'] = $username;
   header("Location:index_logged_in.php");
}
else{
  header ("Location:login.php?id=I
}
mysql_close($con);
```

---

When you save a user password, hash it first.

```
$password = hash('ripemd320',$password )
```

---

```
$password = hash('ripemd320',_POST['Password'] )
$results = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `Username`='$username' AND `Password`='$password'");
```

Comment: i saw no one attacking, just pointing out the numerous flaws - and your help is just dangerous.

Comment: Your "cleaned up code" doesn't even fix the serious liability issue you mention.

Comment: Offer help.  It's a new user and you guys are not doing what you should be doing as in helping!

Comment: the comments do offer help. your code offers noting but the wrong way to do things.

Comment: Can please someone provide me with some help as I am unable to fix the problem. I have been trying for weeks!

Comment: @Dagon the reason I still use mysql_ is because it is more secure then mysqli_.  Just how is it my help is dangerous??

Comment: "mysql_ is because it is more secure then mysqli_" - mind boggled.Evidence - please (honestly)

Comment: "Just how is it my help is dangerous??"

I Think you have just answered your own question.. mysql is definitely not more secure than mysqli.

Comment: @Dagon I am responsible for HIPAA sites.  mysqli_ is a work in progress and introduces new and very serious security vulnerabilities.  I do not need the mysqli_ features, so I am sticking with a version that has no known vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Misunderstood could you please help me with the solution.

Comment: Yes, just try my code and get back to me with what happens.  We can deal with the password later if you care to.

Comment: im no expert - the manual (and every site i have read) told me to move to mysqli - so i did. i'm inclined to believe every one but you.

Comment: @Dagon I don't believe everything I read.  I put more faith in the NIST National Vulnerability Database than a PHP manual.  If it ain't broke why fix it?

Comment: @Misunderstood Work in progress? If you mean "still receives updates to vulnerabilities that are found" as opposed to deprecated ext/mysql, which *doesn't* receive regular updates anymore and will soon be removed from PHP, then you would be correct. Is that a bad thing? Mysqli has been part of PHP for going on 11 years now. It's hardly new.

Comment: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=mysqli+php&search_type=all&cves=on 4 results- all fixed - so um?

Comment: No not a bad thing.  It just doesn't work for me.  When time permits and there is a version with no known vulnerabilities I will assess upgrading at that time.  I am in control of my server.  Depreciated functions do not affect me. I am not going to upgrade unless there is a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: @Dagon now you are the one getting dangerous.  search term "mysql" returns  483  vulnerabilities. See this one:  https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-0411

Comment: "Oracle MySQL Server 5.5.40 and earlier, and 5.6.21 and earlier" whats it got to do with the php mysql api ? you said  php's mysqli_* was less secure than mysql_*